# Is there any way I might turn on light mode for a specific app on macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, ventura

I'm trying to find a way to turn on light mode for a specific app on macOS Ventura, but I can't find an option in the system settings. Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: No such option exists. Some apps have their own settings for Light, Dark, or "Follow System".  What is the app?

Comment: Let's say, like, Xcode

Comment: Xcode... easy example. Settings | General | Appearance | [ System, Light, Dark], for the main App, then pick an appropriate theme for the editor. As benwiggy states, it needs to be implemented in-App.

Comment: Thanks @AndyGriffiths